# PHP Search with join table

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, search

so i have 2 table :

Brand :

- id
- brand_name

Product :

- id
- id_brand (FK)
- nama_product
- harga_product
- warna_product
- berat_produc

i want to search product and returning that brand name, i use this code :

```
   $query = mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT product.* FROM brand 
                                     LEFT JOIN product on brand.id = product.id_brand
                                     WHERE product.nama_product LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
                                     OR product.harga_product LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
                                     OR product.berat_product LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
                                     OR product.warna_product LIKE '%".$keyword."%' 
                                     ORDER BY id ASC");
    $hitung_data = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($hitung_data > 0) {
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['nama_product']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['brand_name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['harga_product']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['berat_product']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data['warna_product']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } } else { ?> 
            <tr>
                <td colspan='4' class="text-center">Tidak ada data ditemukan</td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
```

and suddenly , appear error like this :

```
Notice: Undefined index: brand_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project-Joki\tugaspw2022\admin\dashboard\product_data.php on line 37
```

how do i solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`brand_name` is part of the `brand` table, so you need to select this as well for your results. Instead of:

```
SELECT product.* FROM brand 
LEFT JOIN product on brand.id = product.id_brand
WHERE product.nama_product LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
OR product.harga_product LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
OR product.berat_product LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
OR product.warna_product LIKE '%".$keyword."%' 
ORDER BY id ASC
```

use:

```
SELECT product.*, brand.* FROM brand 
LEFT JOIN product on brand.id = product.id_brand
WHERE product.nama_product LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
OR product.harga_product LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
OR product.berat_product LIKE '%".$keyword."%'
OR product.warna_product LIKE '%".$keyword."%' 
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: now it's error like this :
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in

Comment: @DaffaRakaMahendra: That means there was an error when executing the query. `mysqli_query()` returned `false`. Use `echo mysqli_error($koneksi);`, directly after executing the query, to find out what the problem is. See: [mysqli_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)